# Linux diagnostics script

Tags: linux, diagnostics

There are a huge range of linux diagnostics tools to use, many of them with pretty obvious things to look for.

For example, `hdparm -I /dev/sda` can tell you that your drive is locked, but it is in the format:

```
Security: 
...
        not     locked
```

If that "not" is not there, then it is locked.

It would be nice for a tool to go through every drive and check if they were locked, as well as the million other things that might be wrong.

Is there anything that does this, at least in part?

- This is a start, but too minimal: https://github.com/elliot/borked
- This is a good resource to build your own: https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/System_maintenance

I would like something a little more full featured that comes as a single script which runs standard linux commands. Does anybody know anything like this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You could do something very simple using a loop to call `hdparm` on each of your drives and then `grep` the desired information if I understand you correctly. Something simple like the following will return the locked status for each drive:

```
#!/bin/sh

for i in /dev/sd?; do 
    drvstat="$(sudo hdparm -I $i | grep locked)"
    printf " %s  :  %s\n" $i "$drvstat"
done
```

**Note:** if you do not have `sudo` authority, then remove `sudo` and run the script as root.

**Output**

```
$ bash ./scr/stack/chksdlocked.sh
 /dev/sda  :    not     locked
 /dev/sdb  :    not     locked
 /dev/sdc  :    not     locked
 /dev/sdd  :    not     locked
```

Comment: I'm sorry, this is more of a general question whether there is something that does this accross all standard linux diagnostic tools to give you a detailed report of device health (not just hdparm, that is just an example)

Comment: Sorry I misunderstood your question. I've used Linux exclusively personally and as a business backend for 16 years and other than a few fad apps that pop up, and then quickly fade to dormant sorceforge projects, there isn't a general cross-platform computer statistics/health package. There are many projects, but none known as the goto package for this type of information. Linux has had the one-tool that does one thing and does it well philosophy since its beginnings that has led to the small utilities like `hdparm` and `ps`, etc.. rather than a one-size fits all supertool.

Comment: no problem. I looked and I don't think one exists, which is rediculous imo, so I rolled my own.